# what does "node = node.next" mean?

Tags: java

In singly linked list, it is specified that

```
 public class ListNode {
       int val;
       ListNode next;
       ListNode(int x) {val = x;}
 }
```

In the code, it says

```
ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
s = 7;
result.next = new ListNode(s);
result = result.next;
System.out.println(result.next);
```

I am not sure why I did not get what I want. First, when I return `result.next`, I think the pointer should travel to the beginning of the LinkedList and give me `7`but actually it prints nothing. Second, what is the meaning of`result = result.next`? Does it mean that the pointer moves to the next node? Third, I only want to put `7` in the ListNode, but if I do not put the sentence `ListNode result = new ListNode(0);`the program will fail in compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really that obvious what you are trying to do.

Perhaps these comments will help:

```
// create a new ListNode object with content 0, and put a reference to it
// in 'result'. At this stage it's 'next' field is null.
ListNode result = new ListNode(0);

s = 7;

// create a new ListNode object with content 7 and a null 'next' field,
// and make the first ListNode object's 'next' field refer to it.
result.next = new ListNode(s);

// now lose the reference to the first object, and instead make 'result'
// point to the second object. At this stage its 'next' field is still null.
result = result.next;

// now print the contents of the 'next' field of the second object, which
// will be null.
System.out.println(result.next);
```

Re your first question, perhaps you meant to print `result.val` at the end, which will indeed be 7. Printing an object reference is not going to give you the `val` field of that object without further work (e.g. overriding `toString()`)

Re your second question, per the comments above, yes, you are effectively moving one step along the linked list, so 'result' now points to the second `ListNode` you allocated (contents `7`).

I don't understand your third question. You have allocated two `ListNode`s. If you only wanted one, then do:

```
result = new ListNode(7);
```

Comment: Two quibbles: I think the situation would be clearer if you mentioned `.next` in your second comment ... `create a new ListNode object with content 7, leaving its .next as nil, and make the first ListNode object's 'next' field refer to it.` 2nd: _"Printing an object reference is never going to give you the content of that object."_ — result.next is a ListNode, and in Java printing it could get you what you want _**if**_ you override `ListNode.toString()`

Comment: @StephenP fixed. And also fixed `nil` vs `null` (too much time with GoLang!)

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I return the whole result? I mean,return both "0" and "7"?

Comment: If you return `result` (and don't do `result  = result.next`) you are effectively returning the whole list, because each node contains a reference to the next node on the list, so by returning the first node, you return (effectively) the whole list. If you want to return them as (e.g.) an array of numbers (no other structure), you will need to iterate through your list and put them into an array, then return that.

Comment: I tried to use return "result" but it only prints out the last node.

Comment: As I said, if you use `return result` and want the whole list to be done, you need to remove `result = result.next`. However, it still won't magically 'print out' the whole list. It will merely return a reference to the first item in the list. To print our the whole list you need to iterate through it in whatever calls your method.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting this error is that result.next when you call System.out.println(result.next) is null.  Lets walk through the code line by line:

```
ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
//--this creates a node result : [0] -> null
//                                ^result pointing to this node
s = 7;
result.next = new ListNode(s);
//--this sets result.next to a new node with value 7 : [0] ->  [7] -> null
//                                                      ^result ^result.next
result = result.next;
//--this moves result over to '7' node : [0] -> [7] -> null
//                                               ^result ^result.next
System.out.println(result.next);
//--from this: [0] -> [7] -> null
//                     ^result ^result.next
//we can see that at this point in time, result.next = null
```

To answer your questions regarding "what does node = node.next mean", it means that the reference will "slide" to whatever node was the next node.  From the LinkedList visualization:

[0] -> [7] -> null

-^node  ^node.next

after calling:

```
node = node.next;
```

[0] -> [7] -> null

--------^node  ^node.next

(EDIT: Answering a question from comments: )

Iterating over a LinkedList is typically done as follows:

```
ListNode result = new ListNode(0);
result.next = new ListNode(7);
while(result != null){
    System.out.println(result.val);
    result = result.next;'
}
```

Comment: Wow, it is so clear! What if I want to return all the nodes in the LinkedList? I mean [0] and [7]

Comment: Both your answers are great and correct. Sorry the system only allow me to accept one answer.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This is usually done by iterating over the linked list with a reference to the first node (the head of the LinkedList).  I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: Also, do not worry about accepting answers, just mark whichever you feel most accurately answers your question.